# Python Regex - Replacing Non-Alphanumeric Characters AND Spaces with Dash

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace all of the non-alphanumeric characters AND spaces in the following Python string with a dash `-`.  I tried to use the below code, but it only replaced the non-alphanumeric characters with a dash `-` and not the spaces.

`s = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '-', s)`

Original String:  `s = 'ABCDE : CE ; CUSTOMER : Account Number; New Sales'`

How can Python regex be used to replace both the non-alphanumeric characters AND spaces with a dash `-` to get the following target outcome?

Target Outcome:  `s = 'ABCDE---CE---CUSTOMER---Account-Number--New-Sales'`

Answer (score 2):

You were *very close*. You just don't need the `+` , because then that would would replace multiple occurances with just one dash.

You need:

```
re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]', '-', s)
```

**Example**:

```
import re

s = 'ABCDE : CE ; CUSTOMER : Account Number; New Sales'

print(re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]', '-', s))
# ABCDE---CE---CUSTOMER---Account-Number--New-Sales
```

Answer (score 1):

I see spaces translated properly, but your regexp should omit the +

```
import re
s = 'ABCDE : CE ; CUSTOMER : Account Number; New Sales'
re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '-', s)
```

I'm on my phone, but pasting that into https://repl.it/languages/python3 gives me

```
ABCDE-CE-CUSTOMER-Account-Number-New-Sales
```

as expected - spaces translated.

If you want the multiple - characters, lose the + in your regexp:

```
import re
s = 'ABCDE : CE ; CUSTOMER : Account Number; New Sales'
re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]', '-', s)
```

Gives

```
ABCDE---CE---CUSTOMER---Account-Number--New-Sales
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Without `re`:

- A `str` is an iterable, so a comprehension can be used on it.
- [`str.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum)
- [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

```py
s = 'ABCDE : CE ; CUSTOMER : Account Number; New Sales'

''.join(x if x.isalnum() else '-' for x in s)
```

#### Output:

```py
'ABCDE---CE---CUSTOMER---Account-Number--New-Sales'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s='ABCDE : CE ; CUSTOMER : Account Number; New Sales'
s = re.sub(r'\W', '-', s)
```

Hope this helps.

Regards
Aditya Shukla

Comment: \W does not match underscore - not in the original set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[\W_]`:

```
import re
d = re.sub('[\W_]', '-', s)
```

Output:

```
'ABCDE---CE---CUSTOMER---Account-Number--New-Sales'
```